# Fastest way to create the vector of mean of a vector elements in R

Tags: r

I want to create the vector of `mean` which is the  mean of element of first and second, second and third, ... of the vector `x`.

I wrote this code for example :

```
   x = rnorm(10000)
   > system.time(sapply(1:(length(x)-1), function(i)   mean(c(x[i], x[i+1]))))
    user  system elapsed 
    0.24    0.00    0.23
```

Is there a faster and more efficient way to create this vector in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think these are the two fastest approaches base R can give you:

```
head(filter(x, c(0.5, 0.5)), -1)
```

or

```
(head(x, -1) + tail(x, -1)) * 0.5
```

The first one has the advantage that it can easily be generalized to any number of elements. The second one looks a lot like @user1609452 but it is about 40% faster because `head` and `tail` are faster than negative indexing and multiplying by 0.5 is faster than dividing by 2.

```
x = rnorm(100000)
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark((head(x, -1) + tail(x, -1)) / 2,
          (head(x, -1) + tail(x, -1)) * 0.5,
          (x[-length(x)] + x[-1]) / 2,
          (x[-length(x)] + x[-1]) * 0.5,
          rollmean(x, 2),
          head(filter(x, c(0.5, 0.5)), -1))
#                                test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
# 2 (head(x, -1) + tail(x, -1)) * 0.5          100   0.581    1.000     0.478    0.103
# 1     (head(x, -1) + tail(x, -1))/2          100   0.615    1.059     0.522    0.093
# 4     (x[-length(x)] + x[-1]) * 0.5          100   0.786    1.353     0.697    0.091
# 3         (x[-length(x)] + x[-1])/2          100   0.831    1.430     0.736    0.095
# 6  head(filter(x, c(0.5, 0.5)), -1)          100   0.583    1.003     0.426    0.158
# 5                    rollmean(x, 2)          100  27.040   46.540    25.445    1.593
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rollmean()` from library `zoo` where you can choose length of rolling window (2 in this case). On my computer this took 0.01 while your solution 0.16.

```
library(zoo)    
y<-rollmean(x,2)
```

### UPDATE - solution with base functions

You can use function `rowMeans()` to calculate mean of each row for matrix made with `head()` and `tail()` of vector x.

```
rowMeans(cbind(head(x,n=-1),tail(x,n=-1)))
```

Comment: I do not want to use other library, just the basis function in R.

Answer (score 3):

Probably just doing something very simple like:

```
(x[-length(x)] + x[-1])/2


> library(rbenchmark)
> benchmark((x[-length(x)] + x[-1])/2, sapply(1:(length(x)-1), function(i)   mean(c(x[i], x[i+1]))))
                                                            test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2 sapply(1:(length(x) - 1), function(i) mean(c(x[i], x[i + 1])))          100  20.548  446.696    20.329    0.004
1                                      (x[-length(x)] + x[-1])/2          100   0.046    1.000     0.044    0.000
  user.child sys.child
2          0         0
1          0         0
```